# Design Pattern Selection Chain of Responsibility With Shared Links

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, plugins, service

I am working on a new tool for my work to control a system. The software should be capable of accepting inputs from a variety of sources, DB monitor, HTTP inputs, other Ethernet Inputs, and who knows what will come, then based on these inputs, signal the system to perform different functions.

So far I have written an interface IInputMonitor which is the base interface for classes that get inputs. IInputMonitor has a member IRequestHandler which is responsible for handling requests that originate at this input monitor. This looks like:

```
public interface IInputMonitor
{
    bool Start(IRequestHandler handler);

    bool Start();

    bool Stop();

    IRequestHandler RequestHandler
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}


public interface IRequestHandler
{
    IRequestHandler NextHandler
    {
        get;
    }

    bool HandleRequest(Request request);

    bool Start();

    bool Stop();
}
```

Most requests will pertain to manipulating the system, but some requests could perform ancillary functions, because of this I originally envisioned the IRequestHandler class implementing a CoR pattern. This way system based requests can be handled by the main system, and other functions can get passed along to a class designed for handling that particular request.

My issue here is that different input monitors can share a single request handler but not not all the handler links in a chain. Strictly following the CoR pattern here would result in something like a tree or long wasteful chains.

To sidestep this I made a special IRequestHandler that functions like a dispatcher, somewhat like the Observer pattern????

```
    internal class SharedRequestHandler : IRequestHandler
{

    private List<IRequestHandler> sharedHandlers;
    private HashSet<string> sharedHandlersIds;
    private List<IRequestHandler> ownedHandlers;
```

This class manages lists of handlers and forwards requests through them.

**I feel like this is a messy pattern. A handler could be a single CoR chain if its simple, or be a SharedRequestHandler which forwards requests through a chain it its self maintains. Children of the SharedRequestHandler could also be small chain's themselves if they were setup as such. Is it normal to mix & match patterns like this? Is there a better pattern for this sort of system? I want to keep things flexible for future additions, but avoid making the system so complicated its impossible to follow and understand**

Comment: I am not sure to understand your issue with the CoR pattern. But for me if you share the first IRequestHandler of your chain between input monitors, it 'll share all the chain between input monitors.

Comment: Basically in my current setup I am sharing a link (Handler) between different chains, because of this that link can't really store a reference to the next part of the chain in that handler unless I wan't the chain to be common across different Inputs which I don't.

To solve that I added the reference based chain SharedRequestHandler, but this feels like an abuse of patterns. I am just looking to see if there is a better way to tackle this sort of problem, or if this meshing of patterns is acceptable.